# Dividing a roadnetwork into intersections in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, intersection

I have a shapefile showing New Zealand's road network, and I need to break up roads at their intersections for my analysis but I haven't been able to do so.

So far I've tried Vector>Analysis Tools>Line intersections to create points at the intersections, and then SAGA>split lines at points, but QGIS kept crashing when it was attempting the second half. I've also tried SAGA >split lines with lines, but this also crashed QGIS.

The result I'm hoping for is to be able to export a shapefile with the existing road network, with the network divded into individual strings at their intersections.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Please provide more details, e.g. what you tried so far, what your result should look like, and an example of the level of detail as a screenshot.

Comment: @IanTurton Thanks for the welcome! So far I've tried Vector>Analysis Tools>Line intersections to create points at the intersections, and then SAGA>split lines at points, but QGIS kept crashing when it was attempting the second half. I've also tried SAGA >split lines with lines, but this also crashed QGIS.

Comment: @Erik, so far I've tried Vector>Analysis Tools>Line intersections to create points at the intersections, and then SAGA>split lines at points, but QGIS kept crashing when it was attempting the second half. I've also tried SAGA >split lines with lines, but this also crashed QGIS. The result I'm hoping for is to be able to export a shapefile with the existing road network, with the network divded into individual strings at their intersections. I'm sorry, I'm not sure how to add screenshots in here

Comment: please use the [edit] button to add these details to your question

Comment: You might look at the v.clean tool in the GRASS section of Processing.  There also is a split with lines tool in Vector-Overlay.  As for SAGA,  I have used the SAGA program directly to run a tool which didn't run in QGIS, although it takes a bit to get used to the SAGA interface, but since you aren't using it for a map it isn't bad.  SAGA probably came with your QGIS install.

Answer (score 0):

You can use processing algorythm **native:splitwithlines**